# How can I play the mp3 file from Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, media-player

I downloaded the mp3 file from a Url and save it in a Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS by the following code:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"d1.mp3");
```

I checked the file can downloaded properly. Now I want to play this d1.mp3 file, but when I press the play button it doesn't start to play a music! it looks I am have problem when I use "setDataSource". I will appreciated if you check my code and let me where I made a mistake.

```
private void initMediaPlayer()
{
    String PATH_TO_FILE = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/d1.mp3";
    mp = new  MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
        mp.prepare();
        Toast.makeText(this, PATH_TO_FILE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_NotStarter;
        textState.setText("- IDLE -");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Error;
        textState.setText("- ERROR!!! -");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Error;
        textState.setText("- ERROR!!! -");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Error;
        textState.setText("- ERROR!!! -");
    }

}

public void play(View view) {
    initMediaPlayer();
    mp.start();           
}
```

Comment: whats the values of `PATH_TO_FILE ` you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` (for app downloads) or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` for full path to downloaded file.

Comment: Dear Andriy, Thanks for your respond. Unfortunately still the problem is exist. As you said for download I changed the code: request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath(),"d1.mp3"); and for creating media player I used the following code: mp = new MediaPlayer();
        String PATH_TO_FILE = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + "/d1.mp3";
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(PATH_TO_FILE));

Comment: You should change this: `String PATH_TO_FILE = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/d1.mp3";` line to `String PATH_TO_FILE = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/d1.mp3";` not for download.

Comment: the file is stored in Device storage and following path: Android/data/"package name"/files/storage/emulated/0/Download/d1.mp3 it seems the address of mp3 file in MediaPlayer.create is still can not find this file.

Comment: So try (for testing) just hardcode `String PATH_TO_FILE = "Android/data/"package name"/files/storage/emulated/0/Download/d1.mp3"`. If this works than print to Log this `String PATH_TO_FILE = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/d1.mp3"` line (something like `Log.d("TEST",  "PATH_TO_FILE = " +PATH_TO_FILE)`);

Comment: Thanks for your respond. As you said also I used straight address either for downloading the file or reading the file, but didn't work. I used both method MediaPlayer.create and setDataSource, none of them worked. By using Mediaplayer.create the immediately stopped but setDataSource had no reaction. I am really confused because I checked with code to show the existence of file by using straight address, but displayed not exist! It looks it can't see the file! Also in Manifest I gave permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Should I put my whole project?

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but I've suffered from the same problem and I solved it by adding one line to your code 
after setting DataSource

```
mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
```

Add PrepareAsync

```
mp.prepareAsync();
```

This solved the issue for me